# Covariant derivative vs partial derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, differentiation, vector-fields

**Question**

$\partial_\mu \vec{V} = 0$, does this imply that $\nabla_\mu V^\kappa = 0$ ?

**My argument**

For any vector $\vec{V}$ we can write that $V=V^\kappa \vec{g_\kappa}$ with $\vec{g_\kappa} = \partial \vec{r}/\partial r^\kappa$ such that:

$$0= \partial_\mu \vec{V} = \partial_\mu(V^\kappa \vec{g}_\kappa) = \partial_\mu (V^\kappa) \vec{g_\kappa} + V^\kappa \partial_\mu(\vec{g_\kappa}) = \partial_\mu (V^\kappa) \vec{g_\kappa} + V^\kappa \Gamma_{\mu\kappa}^\rho \vec{g_\rho} = \partial_\mu (V^\kappa) \vec{g_\kappa} + V^\rho \Gamma_{\mu\rho}^\kappa \vec{g_\kappa} = \nabla_\mu (V^\kappa) \vec{g_\kappa}$$

projecting onto the different basis vectors than gives the result that $\nabla_\mu V^\kappa = 0$

**Additional question**

If this is true, and we consider a translation in space $\vec{x} \rightarrow \vec{x} + \vec{a}$ with $\vec{a}$ constant. Do we than find that $\nabla_\mu a_\nu = 0$?

Comment: Are you sure that $\partial_\mu(\vec{e_\kappa}) = \Gamma_{\mu\kappa}^\rho \vec{e_\rho}$.  I think   $\nabla_\mu(\vec{e_\kappa}) = \Gamma_{\mu\kappa}^\rho \vec{e_\rho}$.

Comment: @SaksithJaksri 
 
Yeah I know that equation but it contradicts what is being said in this reference. onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/9783527618132.app6/pdf I went trough the math in that reference and can't find any holes...

Comment: @SaksithJaksri I have found the full version of that book and it turns out that the $\vec{e_\kappa}$ that he is reffering to are NOT the normalized unit vectors !

Comment: Isn't the covariant derivative of a function just the directional derivative? Not sure how to interpret the last equal sign. I tried to get an expression for it before which used the koszul formula and it needed two vectors to be computed.

Comment: @Emil, Well in the last equal sign I introduce the usual covariant derivative .

Comment: @gertian It looks like it doesnt wrap around both the component and the vector though. The definition I have understood needs 2 vectors, not 1 vector and 1 component/function.

Comment: @Emil I use the fact that $\nabla_\mu A^\kappa = \partial_\mu A^\kappa + \Gamma_{\mu\rho}^\kappa A^\rho$

Comment: @gertian I think you are mixing the notation where no vector is ever written out and the notation where the vectors are written out. I think your last step is wrong, but since abstract tensor notation is just guesswork for me (never understood where the tensor basis vectors are) I can not prove it to you. Just a warning.

Comment: I am 99.99999% sure that a scalar product in the second argument of a covariant derivative plops out asccording to liebniz rule. Which is another reason why I suspect your parenthesis is wrong in the last step.

Comment: @Emil I wrote down an extra step. I just change ghost indices $\rho$ and $\kappa$

Answer (score 2):

The initial problem comes when you start with the quantity $\partial_{\mu} \vec{V}$. This is not a valid operation - remember generally vectors are defined in the tangent space - they are linear differential operators. You can only operate on the *components* of the vector i.e. $\partial_{\mu} V^{\mu}$.

Instead, for some path in a manifold with coordinates $x^i$ and parameterized by $\lambda$, we can ask how does the geometrical object $\vec{V}$ change along the path?

In this case we have,

\begin{align*}
\frac{d\vec{V}}{d \lambda} = \frac{d}{d \lambda}(V^i e_i) &= \frac{d V^i}{d \lambda} e_i + V^i \frac{d e_i}{d\lambda} \\
&= \frac{d V^i}{d \lambda} e_i + V^i \frac{d e_i}{dx^b} \frac{dx^b}{d \lambda}\\
&=\frac{d V^i}{d \lambda} e_i + V^i \Gamma_{ib}^c e_c \frac{dx^b}{d \lambda}
\end{align*}

If we are just interested in how the components of the vector change, then we can relabel the indices and drop the basis vectors such that

$$ \frac{D V^i}{d \lambda} = \frac{d V^i}{d \lambda} + V^i \Gamma^a_{ic} \frac{d x^c}{d \lambda}$$